# How to find property name by accessor method name with popular library?

Tags: java, spring, reflection, apache-commons-beanutils

I have my custom annotation, which I am applying to some getters and/or setters.

Not I want some processing. I will find annotated methods and then wish to calculate property name of this method. I.e. I need to cut-out the "get" or "set" or "is" prefix and then do some decapitalization.

Are there some common library like Spring or Apache BeanUtils, which provide all these functions for me?

Comment: What part is the problem, finding the annotated methods, or doing the processing you need? Presume this is run-time processing.

Comment: Would like all parts in one place/library. For example, I found various methods for searching annotated methods like `getMethodsWithAnnotation`

Comment: meaning you want to know annotated method names programmatically ?

Answer (score 0):

PFB sample code to get method names having Custom Annotation :

**Find Methods with Custom Annotations**:

```
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class FindAnnotations {

    public static void getAnnotations(Class clazz) {
        for (Method method : clazz.getDeclaredMethods()) {
            for (Annotation annotation : method.getDeclaredAnnotations()) {
                if (annotation.annotationType() == CustomAnnotation.class) {

                    // do your processing here
                    String name = method.getName();
                    System.out.println(name + " : "
                            + name.replaceAll("get|set|is", ""));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        getAnnotations(ChildTest.class);
    }
}
```

**ChildTest uses CustomAnnotation:**

```
public class ChildTest {

    private String childName;

    @CustomAnnotation
    public void setChildName(String childName) {
        this.childName = childName;
    }

    @CustomAnnotation
    public String getChildName() {
        return this.childName;
    }

    @CustomAnnotation
    public boolean isChildName(String childName) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Custom Annotation Class:**

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface CustomAnnotation {
    String info() default "";
}
```